# What's the recommended version of ECMAScript that my TypeScript should compile to?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016, tsconfig

I'm working through Angular2 tutorials, and I've been going through each section until I opened the `tsconfig.json` and stopped at the following: `"target": "es5"`. This means that I compile to ECMAScript 5.

```
{    
   "compilerOptions": {    
     "target": "es5",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "removeComments": false,
     "noImplicitAny": false
   } 
 }
```

I'm currently using ES5. Should I change the target to `"es6"` or `"es7"`? What's the advantage of using later versions?

Comment: Who is *"we"*? Most current browsers support only ES5 natively, hence that's the most common setting at the moment.

Comment: ES isn't supported by all browsers yet http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/, es7 is far far away. You can transcode to es6 only if you use Typescript in Node.JS, not browser app

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I wasn't sure which version to stick to, but I will continue to use ES5 for now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's not true. Latest versions of Edge, Firefox and Chrome support over 90% of ES 6. Compiling to ES 5 is necessary only if you have to support IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It mostly depends on the browsers you're supporting.

If you need to support IE, old safari or mobile browsers, go with `es5`,

if you need to support only latest chrome and firefox or edge and Safari 10, you probably can go with `es6`.

But I'd suggest you go with `es5` for now.